# SVG + CSS; Clippath in flexbox environment

Tags: html, css, svg

i think this might be very simple for some of you. i just want to mask an image with an SVG-graphic.

i created an SVG with the clipPath element in it:

```html
<svg id="heart-path-container" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
  <clipPath id="heart-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M24.85,10.126c2.018-4.783,6.628-8.125,11.99-8.125c7.223,0,12.425,6.179,13.079,13.543
            c0,0,0.353,1.828-0.424,5.119c-1.058,4.482-3.545,8.464-6.898,11.503L24.85,48L7.402,32.165c-3.353-3.038-5.84-7.021-6.898-11.503
            c-0.777-3.291-0.424-5.119-0.424-5.119C0.734,8.179,5.936,2,13.159,2C18.522,2,22.832,5.343,24.85,10.126z">    
            </path>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

and an SVG with the image in it:

```html
<svg id="heart-image-container" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
  <image class="clip-image" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490810277975-e64342ceecf0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=88e69bf894f334456f8ae269752556e1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80"></image>
</svg>
```

i basically say in CSS that this image should be clipped with that SVG clipPath element.

```css
.clip-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: url(#heart-path);
}
```

but it does not do it.

i created a fiddle to show that nothing is getting clipped.

what am i doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/Marvbuster/pen/MXvbXo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `objectBoundingBox` coordinates, the corrdinate have to be between 0 and 1.  Your clip path coordinates go up to approx 50, so your clip path is 50x too big.

The simple fix is use a `transform` to scale your path back down to the correct size.

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

svg{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.clip-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: url(#heart-path);
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section{
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <section></section>
  
  <section>
    <svg x="0px" y="0px">
      <clipPath id="heart-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M24.85,10.126c2.018-4.783,6.628-8.125,11.99-8.125c7.223,0,12.425,6.179,13.079,13.543
                 c0,0,0.353,1.828-0.424,5.119c-1.058,4.482-3.545,8.464-6.898,11.503L24.85,48L7.402,32.165c-3.353-3.038-5.84-7.021-6.898-11.503
                 c-0.777-3.291-0.424-5.119-0.424-5.119C0.734,8.179,5.936,2,13.159,2C18.522,2,22.832,5.343,24.85,10.126z"
              transform="scale(0.02,0.02)"></path>
      </clipPath>
    </svg>

    <svg id="heart-image-container" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">

      <image class="clip-image" xlink:href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490810277975-e64342ceecf0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=88e69bf894f334456f8ae269752556e1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80"></image>

    </svg>
  
  
  </section>
  
  <section></section>
</div>
```